# How to disable autocomplete option in msdropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, msdropdown

Autocomplete option in new msdropdown version is a cool feature.

But for some reasons, I dont that feature in my msdropdown. So how to disable that option?

I dont want to edit the msdropdown js file, because I may need that feature in some other area of my application. I could not find any option in their documentation.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in function to disable the autocomplete feature, but you can use css to hide the input element used for the autocomplete.

The autocomplete is an input defined by the plugin as `<select id>_titleText` so you can use for example:

```
#payments2_titleText{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/9DLjL/

Comment: Why is not the accepted answer anymore? Any problem with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

Find the dropdown container div class name and hide it

```
$(".dopdownwrapper_div").hide();
```